# Sharepoint newsfeed image authorization

Tags: sharepoint-server, newsfeed, mobile, microsoft-access, image-display

I want to display images which are in my organization SharePoint news feed page in a xamarin app. Image URL needs an authorization. How to give this authorization.

Image URL : `"https://organizationName.sharepoint.com/Lists/Group%20News/Attachments/6500/Cove%29Page.png"`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can get the image data using SharePoint REST API.

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/<folder name>/<file name>')/$value
```

Convert data to Base64-encoded string.

```
"data:image/png;base64, " + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Then set Base64-encoded string to the src attribute of the image.

**Articles**:

[Files and folders REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx)

[Xamarin Android Image Rotate Animation In Android App Using Visual Studio 2015](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-image-rotate-animation-in-android-app-using-visual-studio-2015/)